# Spring session factory is always null for multiple datasources

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

I am trying to @Autowire multiple Hibernate SessionFactory inside my application through Spring 4 SessionFactory DI. Only one Datasource(epi) is getting injected properly but the other two Datasources SessionFactory values are always null.
Two of them are oracle database and the other one is DB2. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is my spring-Datasource.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="epiStageDS" 
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="epi"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="" />
    <property name="username" value="" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="eveDS"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="" />
    <property name="username" value="" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Session factory for EPI db -->
    <bean id="episessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="epi" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>edu.eve.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql:false}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql:false}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<!-- EVE DS SESSION FACTORY -->

    <bean id="eveSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="eveDS" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>edu.eve.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql:false}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql:false}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Session factory for Stage DS db -->

    <bean id="stageDsSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="epiStageDS" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>edu.eve.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.db2.show_sql:false}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.db2.format_sql:false}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="epiTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="episessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="eveTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="eveSessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="stageDsTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="stageDsSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"

    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

Here are the classes in which I am autowiring SessionFactory.

Below sessionFactory is getting injected perfectly.

```
@Transactional("epiTransactionManager")
public class EpiBaseService {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("episessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Autowired sessionFactory value are always null for below DS.

```
@Transactional("stageDsTransactionManager")
public class StageDsBaseService {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("stageDsSessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


@Transactional("eveTransactionManager")
public class EveBaseService {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("eveSessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Please tell me what i am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I know what I was doing wrong. I was creating a new object of service class rather than @Autowiring inside the spring controller. I was doing this in order to make sure that my sessionfactory is not null but looks like that's not the correct way to do it. You have to use the Spring IOC container to inject the service class in your controller. Now all the sessionFactories are properly connected to specified datasources.